# logservice.fetch() is not returning anything

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, logging

The following code is used to fetch logs from app engine for further processing. However I do not know how to use the result of logservice.fetch to access log messages now??

```
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api.logservice import logservice
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED = False

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):  
        requestlogs = logservice.fetch(start_time=1332200000, end_time=1332249954, offset=None, minimum_log_level=logservice.LOG_LEVEL_INFO, include_incomplete=False, include_app_logs=True, version_ids=None, batch_size=None)
        self.response.out.write(requestlogs)
        c=0
        for iter in requestlogs:
           c=c+1  
        print c
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/logs', MainPage)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning anything, or your page isn't displaying anything? Using `print` in a webapp request handler is a Bad Idea; use `self.response.out.write()`

Comment: Hmm....actually it is giving a blank page....
ok .....I will try self.response.out.write() ...By the way what does the logservice.fetch actually returns.....I mean what are the attributes of the object returned.....I have no clue how to access the log messages after fetching the logs

Comment: @MayankKhandelwal This is all in the documentation - have you read it?

Comment: I did read it.....Somehow...was unable to implement it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import logservice

MAX_LOGS_TO_READ = 10

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):  
    request_logs = logservice.fetch()
    current_log = 0
    for log in request_logs:
      if current_log > MAX_LOGS_TO_READ:
        break
    self.response.out.write(log.combined)
```

A couple of comments..

- Use self.response.out.write() to write data to the response output stream.
- fetch() returns an iterator of RequestLog objects. You can use this iterator then in a for loop to go over the set of logs the iterator knows about.
- RequestLog objects return a number of attributes, which are mostly documented here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/requestlogclass.html

Comment: I have been using a slightly modified code as suggested by you.....It was working fine till now....However now when I wanted to access the logfile of one entire day I got the following error------ 
Status:500   
**OverQuotaError: The API call logservice.Read() required more quota than is available**